# Getting the latitude and longitude of the point in between (by percentage) two points on Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 21.9072222, lng: -47.715},
    zoom: 3
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('derby-to-lima'),
      mapOptions);

  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.9834124, -1.5863153), new google.maps.LatLng(-12.0553442, -77.0451853)],
    strokeColor: "#008CBA",
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I want to draw another line on top of the existing one that stops at the point in between the two points, which can be changed by percentage. It's kind of hard to explain, but imagine the first point is the start, and the last is the end. You are given how far a runner currently is by the percentage of the way through they are. Now show how far they are (assuming they ran in a straight line).

Thanks, I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: [**`google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate()`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Comment: possible duplicate of [latLng from polyLine Percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128954/latlng-from-polyline-percentage/19129543#19129543)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Midpoint of route in google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176555/midpoint-of-route-in-google-maps/23185777#23185777)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the geo position at given time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562799/calculate-the-geo-position-at-given-time/25568700#25568700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Dr.Molle load the `geometry` library and use the method `interpolate`.

```
var startPoint =  new google.maps.LatLng(53.9834124, -1.5863153); 
var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.0553442, -77.0451853);
var percentage = 0.5; 
var middlePoint = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(startPoint, endPoint, percentage);
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8pj2v634/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this I'll try it out when I get back to my computer.