# Get location after travel x distance on a Google Maps route

Tags: google-maps

Just want to verify this. I have checked Google Maps API, couldn't seem to find this one.

Bascially if I use Google Maps to calculate a route from point A to point B. I wonder if there is an API that Google provides to calculate what's the location/coordinate if you travel x meters following the route from point A?

Or I have to break down the routes returned by Google and calculate them one by one. I assume it would be something like:

```
var travelledDistance   
var routeDistanceTotal  
for route x in routes  
var routeDistanceTotal = routeDistanceTotal + (route x end - route x start)   
if( routeDistanceTotal >= travelledDistance) {  
    final location = point end - routeDistanceTotal - travelled distance 
}    
else{  
    continue to next route  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for your help. Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128954/latlng-from-polyline-percentage. the method GetPointAtDistance is exactly what I am after. Google doesn't have an official one, I am bit surprised. Anyway, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

GetPointAtDistance from http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js.

From [latLng from polyLine Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128954/latlng-from-polyline-percentage) and thanks to @geocodezip